# Print a python list line by line

Tags: python, sorting, newline

How can I get the results of my print onto new lines? The list being printed is a first name, surname and email address, so I want each one on a new line.

```
import csv

f = open('attendees1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

attendee_details = []

for row in csv_f:
    attendee_details.append(row[0:4])



sortedlist =[sorted(attendee_details, key=lambda x:x[0])]

print (sortedlist)
```

Comment: Perhaps use `print('\n'.join(sortedlist))`

Comment: use `for i in sortedList: print i`

Comment: @RafaelCardoso: print(i), OP might be using python3, see last line

Comment: @pytonbeginner post the contents of `sortedlist` variable. And also post your expected output.

Comment: As an aside, if the first row of the line contains the column name, you might want to use [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of `csv.reader`. I find that in most cases, the datasets have the column name, and it's more readable code when we write `row['first_name']` than `row[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, sortedlist)))
```

This will work for all lists. If the list already consists of strings, the `map` is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using Python 3, you can also do this:

```
print(*sortedlist, sep='\n')
```

This unpacks the list and sends each element as an argument to `print()`, with `'\n'` as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop. ie, replace the last two lines with this

```
for i in sorted(attendee_details, key=lambda x:x[0]):
    print(i)
```

Note that

```
sortedlist =[sorted(attendee_details, key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

line of code will create list of list.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way would be as follows:

```
print(*sorted(runnerup), sep='\n')
```